# How to get host entries of a domain

Tags: hosting, dns

We want to get host entries of a domain.

Given a domain name (let us say: google.com) I need to get the host records (ex: CNAME, TXT etc..records).
Is it possible to get them even when we do not have the control on the domain (i.e domain not purchased by us?

Actually, my requirement is that when users enter domain name in my application (which is in development), I want to check if the domain belongs to them or not (I will be asking them to add some random string as TXT record) and then will read the TXT record of that domain in the backend and verify the domain.
I think google does this (when we setup google apps account).
Any pointers in this will help a lot.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can only get records from a particular name (hostname or domain name)

To get a txt entry from a particular name run:

dig TXT [name]

more information about dig: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Information_Groper

If you have the control of the dns server of the domain you can allow dns zone transfer which enables you to get full configuration of a domain. But, most of the time, this is forbidden.

In this case you will run dig AXFR [domainname]

Comment: Thanks! The command is very much useful. Here is a link to java implementation i found on internet: http://www.xbill.org/dnsjava/dnsjava-current/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'dig' for this from the command line to see what output you are to get for a given domain, then, in php you can use dns_get_record to get the same information.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php

Answer (score 0):

The `dig` command in LInux, can do that.

For example:

```
dig stackoverflow.com TXT
```